# Guessing game using a tester class

Tags: java

I am creating a Guessing game program in java code. I am having an issue with the main class and the tester class running. Any help would be appreciated. The instructions for the game are The computer generates a random # and the user must guess that number in 7 or fewer guesses. If the guesses exceed 7, then the game is over and the user is asked if they want to 'play again?'

Here is my guess class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Guess 
{
    int computersNumber; // A random number picked by the computer.
    int usersGuess = 0;      // A number entered by user as a guess.
    int guessCount = 0;      // Number of guesses the user has made.

    Random random = new Random();

    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);


    public Guess(int n)
    {
        usersGuess = n;
    }



   public boolean getGuess()
   {
       boolean isValid = false;
            if (isValid)
              {
                  return false;
              }

            if (usersGuess == computersNumber)

              {  
                  return true;
              }

            return isValid;
    }

   public boolean isGuessCorrect()
   {
       return getGuess() == computersNumber;
   }

   public int getCount()
   {
       guessCount ++;
       return guessCount;
   }

        boolean playAgain;


}
```

Tester/main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessTester 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Let's play a game!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The computer will generate a number between 0 and 100. You will have up to seven guesses"
                + "to figure out what the number is. Good luck!");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("What is your first guess? ");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    Guess guess = new Guess(n);

    if (guess.getGuess == computersNumber) 
    {
        System.out.println("That's Correct! ");
    }
    if (getCount == 7) 
    {
        System.out.println("You lose, you didn't get the number in 7 guesses.");
    }

    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? ");
    in.nextBoolean();

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Thanks for playing.");

    in.close();

}

}
```

Comment: For your thread to have an answer, it must have a question.

Comment: You'll have to re-read your lesson materials. You are using variables you have not declared or initialized, calling methods without parentheses or object reference, and you are not actually creating a `Guess` object to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things in your code that don't compile. Did you post all your code?

First things first: if you have a `class` `Guess` and you want to access its methods, you need to instantiate an `Object` of that `class` first:

```
int n = in.nextInt();
Guess guess = new Guess(n);
```

Next, in order to actually access a method of `guess` it is written like this:

```
if (guess.getGuess() == computersNumber) {
   System.out.println("That's Correct! ");
}
```

However in your example, the variable `computersNumber` is not defined in the main class but it is a member of the `Guess` class. Since both the `computersNumber` and the method `getGuess()` are part of the `Guess` class it would be better to actually access them from within that class and do the comparison there. Maybe in a separate method:

```
public class Guess{
   ....
   public boolean isGuessCorrect(){
      return getGuess() == computersNumber;
   }
}
```

Another thing I saw in your `Guess` class is that you access some boolean variable in `getGuess()`, which is not defined:

```
if (!isValid) {
    return false;
}
```

Where does `isValid` come from? where is it defined?

**Edit:** a little hint for the road:

You can generate a random number between 0 and 100 like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);  // this will be a number between 0 and 100
int another = random.nextInt(1000);   // you can reuse the random object and generate more numbers
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! It has been very helpful and I changed my code around a bit. Maybe you could take another look? What doesn't make sense to me is the public boolean isGuessCorrect method. I am getting errors when that code is written in java? I am all new to this and pratically teaching myself by research on the web.